# DLL obfuscator - what kind of obfuscator is this?

Tags: dll

when I am looking for packet editor, I found open project on http://www.packeteditor.com/
when I learn how it works, I see that the application is injecting a dll named WSPE.dat, when I load this WSPE.dat to ida pro, I found it was a dll that has been obfuscated.
and it was something like this :
[image: SteveW obfuscator]

what is that SteveW section? I also see a lot of this obfuscator on other dll, but protectionId scan result it wasn't being packed
with this note :

```
Section [0x0] 'SteveW  ' has a higher physical size than virtual size..
```

and also this :

```
Warning : Import Table is bad !!!
```

here is the dll link :
[WSPE.dat](https://github.com/appsec-labs/Advanced_Packet_Editor/blob/master/Source/PacketEditor/WSPE.dat)

Comment: It looks like it's just a `.text` section as it has executable permission.

Comment: Looks like a custom crypter to me, not really obfuscated. `sub_6464146E` has a small rol/xor/rol loop that's probably decrypting the code.

Comment: I didn't make the DLL open source. I wrote it in MASM (x86 assembly) but the source for it is on a hard drive that I'd have no way to to read anymore. I could write a 64-bit version but it would take quite a while. I haven't worked on the application in a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the code for WSPE.dat and can confirm that I custom wrote the encryption based on the supplied name/key plus the 'invalid' PE heading. So, if a user attempts to modify the PE heading on the drive to allow for debugging of the DLL for a dump then it'll fail to properly decrypt in memory.

Comment: I see, so it's not open source for the wspe.dat right? can't you make x64 version of that dll?